# phpMailer and Google Captcha

Tags: php, phpmailer, recaptcha

Ok so on my website I have a contact form and I use phpMailer to send the emails.  It works fine but I keep getting spam emails.  So I have tried incorporating captcha into the contact form.  I have the initial code for captcha setup but I have no idea where to go from here.  I've tried putting the rest of the code into the statement for captcha but it doesnt work.

Any help would be great

here is the php code:

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Alias the League Google OAuth2 provider class
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;
//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $secret ='';
    $response = $_POST['g-captcha-response'];
    $rempteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $url = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteip");
    $result = json_decode($url,TRUE);

    if($result['success'] == 1) {

    }
}
$name       = $_POST['name'];
$phone      = $_POST['phone'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$message    = $_POST['message'];

//validation
if(empty($name)){
    header("location: ../index.html?nouser");
    exit();
}

if(empty($phone)){
    header("location: ../index.html?nophone");
    exit();
}

if(empty($email)){
    header("location: ../index.html?noemail");
    exit();
}

if(empty($message)){
    header("location: ../index.html?nomessage");
    exit();
}


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
    // SENDER
    // this doesnt work with google use AddReplyTo
    // to be able to reply back to users email
    $mail->setFrom($email, sprintf('%s', $_POST['name']));

    //Recipients
    $mail->addAddress('darrells.webdesign@gmail.com', 'Darrell Pawson Jr');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email);

    //wordwrap
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = sprintf('New Message From %s', $_POST['name']);

    $mail->Body    = $strMessage = sprintf('%s<hr> Phone:  %s', $_POST['message'], $_POST['phone']);
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);

    $okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';
    $errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
    // Try to send the message
    if (!$mail->send()) { // Error
        // Set the error message
        $responseArray = [
            'type' => 'danger',
            'message' => sprintf('There was an error trying to send your message:  %s', $mail->ErrorInfo)
        ];
    } else { // Success
        // Set the success message
        $responseArray = [
            'type' => 'success',
            'message' => $okMessage
        ];
    }
}
finally{
    // Check for an XHR request
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        // Send the header
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        // Send the JSON response
        echo json_encode($responseArray);
    } else {
        // Send the message
        echo $responseArray['message'];
    }
}
```

And here is the js code that goes along with it... (i dont know if it's needed or not)

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#form').validator();

    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "./phpmailer/send.php";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    var messageAlert = ' alert-' + data.type,
                        messageText = data.message,

                        alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        $('#form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        $('#form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to define "doesn't work".

Comment: You're also forging the from address. Don't do that. Put your own address as the from address and the submitter's in a reply-to.

Comment: When I click submit nothing happens, I tried with the code that runs phpMailer inside the if statement for captcha and that didnt work and I didnt know where else go go.  Thats why the code is now outside of the if statement now...